# How is the following text transposed into this hex output?

Tags: text, language-agnostic, hex, translation

INPUT:

```
00:00:00:00     a
                b
                c
                d
                // NEWLINE separating each letter
```

OUTPUT:

```
Scenarist_SCC V1.0

00:00:00:00 9420 13d6 9723 6180 1376 9723 6280 94d6 9723 e380 9476 9723 6480 9420 942c 942f

00:00:01:00 942c
```

Here is some information about [the format](http://www.theneitherworld.com/mcpoodle/SCC_TOOLS/DOCS/SCC_FORMAT.HTML), but I'm struggling to understand how this text transformation is done.

Comment: Short of regurgitating the reference you've already linked to which explains this, what do you want us to say?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is it that you're using to convert the text to that string of Hex? Regardless, it would appear as though the Hex output is peppered with various CC commands. Just looking at the codes in the format document to which you linked I get the following:

> Timecode 00:00:00:00: start pop-on caption (9420), move cursor to row 12, column 12 (13d6), move over three columns (9723), character "a" (6180), move cursor to row 13, column 12 (1376), move over three columns (9723), character "b" (6280), move cursor to row 14, column 12 (94d6), move over three columns (9723), character "c" (e380), move cursor to row 15, column 12 (9476), move over three columns (9723), character "d" (6480), start pop-on caption (9420), clear screen (942c), display caption (942f).
>
> Timecode 00:00:01:00: clear screen (942c)

So whatever program you're using to produce the output is adding the CC formatting, positioning and other commands to the Hex stream.